# R: Find the maximum value of each simulated iteration in R

Tags: r

I need to record the maximum value of 5 observations, simulated 10,000 times.  This is in order to find the mean of these maximum values.

My current code looks like this:

```
mc.sim1 = function(){
   mu = 20; sigma = 4
   (rnorm(5, mu, sigma))
}

m = replicate(10000, mc.sim1())
```

I'm at a loss to explain how to record the maximum of each iteration, rather than the maximum of the whole simulated set using the 'max' function.

Answer (score 0):

If to follow your code, use `dim` to understand what `m` is.
it is a matrix, with a row for each observation of the simulation, and a column for each replication.

a really simple and intuitive loop can look like

```
recorded_max=numeric(dim(m)[2])
for (i in 1:dim(m)[2])
{
  recorded_max[i]=max(m[,i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `apply` to calculate the maximum value per column (since each column represents an iteration in `m`):

```
colMax <- apply(m, 2, max)
```

Also note @shadow's comment below about the `colMaxs` function from the `matrixStats` package.

Comment: The `colMaxs` function from the `matrixStats` package is more than 10 times faster.

Comment: @shadow why dont you post it as a separate answer then?

Comment: Because it's basically the same thing as your answer (with a slight  improvement in speed) and not something that deserves a seperate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple `sapply` would work

```
mc.sim1 = function(...){
   mu = 20; sigma = 4
   max(rnorm(5, mu, sigma))
}

maxdraw <- sapply(seq.int(10000), mc.sim1)
```

At the end `maxdraw` will be a vector of length 10,000 with the maximum of the five random normal variables from each iteration.

Comment: This is definitely an elegant solution to finding the max value per iteration. However, in case the OP needs `m` later on for other purposes, it might be disadvantageous not to create it (as proposed in your solution), especially since it contains random numbers.